# Program the number of rows in Uitable MATLAB depending on the amount of data

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, matlab-table

I am trying to make a uitable in my MATLAB GUI following the examples provided on the MATLAB websites, I was able to create one. However, in my case, the number of rows in the table is dependent upon the size of my data. So I was wondering how can I label the rows appropriately. 
Say may data have N points I want the rows to read 1 2 3 4,.....N

Anyone knows how to modify the code to make it do that?

Here is what I have so far:

```
f = figure('Position',[440 500 461 146]);

% create the data
d = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
A = size(d)


% Create the column and row names in cell arrays 
cnames = {'X-Data','Y-Data','Z-Data'};

for i = 1:A(1)
%%Fills the row names depending on A(1) 
rnames = {'1','2','3'};

end


% Create the uitable
t = uitable(f,'Data',d,...
        'ColumnName',cnames,... 
        'RowName',rnames);
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question, the number of rows displayed is already controlled by the size of the data you provide. Do you mean the size of the  table itself?

Comment: @excaza what I mean is that for example if my data,d, is an array of N numbers I would like the number of rows in my table to be N aswell. And N change

Comment: @excaza oh I see. But okay what about naming the rows. I would like them to be named 1:N.

Comment: @AliP May I suggest something: if you have supplemental requirements, add them to your posted question.